# HttpPost [FromForm] Always contains null

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core

I can't bind a [FromForm] in my IActionResult (ASP.NET Core 2) from C# desktop application.

**In my C# desktop application**, I have the following code:

```
private void SendStats ( object state )
{
    double aCpu = ( ( double )AppDomain.CurrentDomain.MonitoringTotalProcessorTime.Ticks / this.totalRunningTime.Ticks ) * 100;
    double aMemory = ( double )AppDomain.MonitoringSurvivedProcessMemorySize / 1048576;
    string version = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version.ToString();

    Stats anStats = new Stats( this.ID, aCpu, aMemory, version );

    using ( WebRequestHandler handler = new WebRequestHandler() )
    {
        using ( HttpClient client = new HttpClient( handler ) )
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri( STATS_SERVER_URL );
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add( new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue( "application/json" ) );

            try
            {
                var content = new StringContent( anStats.ToJSONString(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" );

                using ( HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsync( STATS_SERVER_URL, content ).Result )
                {
                    if ( response.IsSuccessStatusCode )
                    {
                        // Do nothing
                    }
                } 
            }
            catch ( System.AggregateException ax )
            {
                if ( !( ax.InnerException is HttpRequestException ) )
                    throw;
            }
        }
    }

    this.totalRunningTime += STATS_COLLECTION_PERIOD;
}
```

My Stats class has:

```
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json;
using System.IO;

namespace MyNamespace.Stats
{
    [DataContract]
    public class Stats
    {
        [DataMember]
        private string id;

        [DataMember]
        private double cpu;

        [DataMember]
        private double mem;

        [DataMember]
        private string version;

        public Stats ( string anId, double aCpu, double aMemory, string aVersion )
        {
            this.id = anId;
            this.cpu = aCpu;
            this.mem = aMemory;
            this.Version = aVersion;
        }

        public string ToJSONString ()
        {
             DataContractJsonSerializer aSerializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer ( typeof( Stats ) );

             using ( MemoryStream aMemStream = new MemoryStream() )
             {
                 aSerializer.WriteObject( aMemStream, this );

                 aMemStream.Position = 0;

                 using ( StreamReader aStreamReader = new StreamReader ( aMemStream ) )
                 {
                      return aStreamReader.ReadToEnd();
                 }
            }
       }
   }
}
```

**In my ASP.NET Core 2 application**, I have the following code:

```
[HttpPost("{productKey}")]
[Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")]
public IActionResult Create(string productKey, [FromForm] LegacyStatViewModel item)
{
    NewUsageViewModel aNewUsageViewModel = new NewUsageViewModel
    {
        Cpu = Convert.ToInt32(item.Cpu),
        BinaryVersion = (item.Version == null ? "UNKNOWN" : item.Version),                
        LastConnection = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"),
        Memory = Convert.ToInt32(item.Mem),
        ProductKey = productKey               
    };

    _context.AspNetNewUsages.Add(aNewUsageViewModel);
    _context.SaveChanges();

    return CreatedAtRoute("GetStat", new { ProductKey = aNewUsageViewModel.ProductKey }, item);
}
```

And finally, LegacyStatViewModel has the following code:

```
namespace MyApp.Models.StatsViewModels
{
    public class LegacyStatViewModel
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }

        public double Cpu { get; set; }

        public double Mem { get; set; }

        public string Version { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The IActionResult is called correcty from desktop application. ProductKey parameter has the expected value but all item fields are null or 0.

Note: I can't modify Desktop application.

Comment: Why are you passing JSON as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`? That makes absolutely no sense

Comment: Are you able to see what is the raw request payload posted to your asp.net core app? From the code that you have posted, i don't see anything that matches to product key parameter, all that your desktop app posts is the Json-ized 'Stats' object.

Comment: `I can't modify Desktop application.` client is sending bad data. Says it's sending form data but sends Json. Server will need to take raw data and parse accordingly since client can't change.

Comment: @Thangadurai. STATS_SERVER_URL is something like "https://localhost:44312/api/stats/" + this.LicenseKey where LicenseKey is a string.

Answer (score 1):

> I can't modify Desktop application.

The client is sending bad data.

Says it's sending form data but sends JSON.

Server will need to take raw data from the body of the request and parse accordingly since the client can't change. *(which is poor design IMO as you have now lost the advantage of built in framework features.)*

```
[HttpPost("{productKey}")]
public IActionResult Create(string productKey, [FromBody] string rawData ) {
    LegacyStatViewModel item = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LegacyStatViewModel>(rawData);
    if(item != null){
        NewUsageViewModel aNewUsageViewModel = new NewUsageViewModel {
            Cpu = Convert.ToInt32(item.Cpu),
            BinaryVersion = (item.Version == null ? "UNKNOWN" : item.Version),                
            LastConnection = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"),
            Memory = Convert.ToInt32(item.Mem),
            ProductKey = productKey               
        };

        _context.AspNetNewUsages.Add(aNewUsageViewModel);
        _context.SaveChanges();

        return CreatedAtRoute("GetStat", new { ProductKey = aNewUsageViewModel.ProductKey }, item);
    }
    return BadRequest();
}
```

This action will only work correctly for that client request as you know that it is actually sending JSON and not form encoded data.

Comment: {StatusCode: 415, ReasonPhrase: 'Unsupported Media Type', Version: 1.1, Content: ...} With FromForm, an IActionResult is called but rawData is null.

Comment: @Jafuentes inspect raw request and confirm content type being sent.

Comment: @Jafuentes also try removing the consumes attribute